# Google BigQuery : Is there way to stop converting number into date on web UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery to store logs. I recently realized BigQuery web UI seems to convert number with 16digits into date (like "12/3/2017, 10:00:13 AM") even though actual column type is "string".

Is there any way to stop web UI from doing this?
Data seems fine once I export it into CSV. It's just web UI issue I'm seeing.

Comment: Can you share the table ID for the table that has this issue?  If you'd rather not post it publicly, feel free to send an e-mail to dkitt at google dot com.

Comment: Sorry to get you back late, I just sent email as it's difficult for me to expose project-id / datasetId here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it turned out to be the [Streak extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streak-bigquery-developer/lfmljmpmipdibdhbmmaadmhpaldcihgd) which was doing this automatic conversion into timestamp format.  One of its features is the following:

> 5. Automatically Convert Timestamps to Human Readable Format
>
> AppEngine and BigQuery store timestamps as epoch time which is great for computers and computation, but not so good for a human to read. The extension automatically finds, parses and replaces epoch timestamps with a human friendly date/time rendering.